# Flutter how to make unselect indicator for Tabbar?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I can't make an Unselected indicator;

Comment: You got downvotes because your questions does not meet the standard of asking a question on Stackoverflow. Check those standards  and improve your question to get chance to have an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create custom indicator using Container and change its value with selected index